# Making sure a command has executed in bash

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I have a bash file with commands to merge pcap files. I want to know if there is anyway to make sure a line in bash runs or not. Like in windows bat file we have %ErrorLevel% ¨
Say a command

```
touch -r dcn_file "${dir_dcn}"/"${TAG1_dcn}".pcap
```

How do I make sure this was run?

Comment: you can use `echo $?` which is the return value of the last command executed

Comment: You can also use `set -e` to make bash exit on failure automatically. You can also assign additional code using `trap` to be executed in case of error (or just at the end regardless of errors)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shells are built to do that sort of thing easily.

```
if touch -r dcn_file "${dir_dcn}"/"${TAG1_dcn}".pcap 
then
    echo "Command ran successfully."
else
    echo "Command had an error: $?"
fi
```

You will occasionally find some proprietary command that doesn't exit with 0 status on success and non-zero on failure, but thankfully, those abberations have almost gone extinct.

Comment: Except for `grep` and its variants, where 0 indicates match found, 1 indicates match not found ("failure"?), and codes higher than 2 indicate error.

Answer (score 9):

The bash variable `$?` hold the exit status of the last command run.  For typical programs, the value `0` is success and any other value is failure.  Specific return code should be documented in the man pages of the programs in question.

You can use code like:

```
touch -r dcn_file "${dir_dcn}"/"${TAG1_dcn}".pcap
[ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Command failed: touch: $?"
   return $?
fi
```

To test the return code and then print an error message and have a script exit with the same error code.

Comment: As I read some documentation about `nice` this morning, the command could return the value of niceness of the process instead of 0 on old version